# javascript remove whitespace carriage return

Tags: javascript, string, whitespace, removing-whitespace

how can I remove whitespace and carriage return from a String. I got something like this..

```
exampleName↵
```

but need just the text and not the symbol at the end.

Comment: do u get text from textarea or div?

Comment: From a div. foo.innerText..

Comment: try `textContent` to get text from div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [trim](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) method?

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

Edit based on the comments: I am not sure what character '↵' is... `trim()` is supposed to remove white-space chars including new-line and carriage-return... so what about the following

```
var a="exampleName↵";
a.replace(/↵/g, "")
alert(a)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dbth6tx8/4/

Comment: have u tried `var a="exampleName↵"alert(a.trim())` ?

Comment: yeah. tried trim(). But doesn't work. Need to remove this element "↵"

Comment: I tried `var a="exampleName\n"; alert("'"+a.trim()+"'")` which removes new line... '↵' is then another character

Comment: because trim only removes whitespaces from beginning and end, not carriage return

Comment: Okay Thanks dude. I used .trim() not in the right position. Now it work's :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var s = '   Your string with newline or/and carriage return   ';
s = s.replace(/(?:\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, '');
```

- \r\n for the DOS\Windows world
- \r for the pre-OSX Mac world
- \n for the Unix and Unix-like world

Answer (score 0):

```
var a="exampleName↵"; 

var mystring = a.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');

alert(mystring);
```